# Fail to import a module's css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In my React project, I am using this gem for creating a dashboard: https://github.com/luqin/react-icheck

I copy pasted their first example in my code.

On the Github page, it says I should have import the `css` like this:

```
import 'icheck/skins/all.css'; // or single skin css
```

If I do that, I get the error:

```
ERROR in ./~/icheck/skins/all.css
Module parse failed: node_modules/icheck/skins/all.css Line 3: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| /* iCheck plugin skins
| ----------------------------------- */
| @import url("minimal/_all.css");
| /*
| @import url("minimal/minimal.css");
```

If instead I do the import like this:

```
import 'icheck';
```

There is no more error, but the page doesn't have any checkbox.

So how can I do this import properly?

I also tried using `style-loader` so my code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Checkbox, Radio} from 'react-icheck';
import 'icheck';
require("style!raw!icheck/skins/all.css");

var Criteria = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {showGallery: false, showOtherCriteria: false};
  },

  toggleShowGallery: function() {
    this.setState({showGallery: !this.state.showGallery});
  },

  toggleShowOtherCriteria: function() {
    this.setState({showOtherCriteria: !this.state.showOtherCriteria});
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>

        <div onClick={this.toggleShowOtherCriteria} className="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-default">Cold</button>
        </div>

        {style.use()}
        {this.state.showOtherCriteria
          ?

          <div onClick={this.toggleShowGallery} id="channels" className="span12">

            <Checkbox
              checkboxClass="icheckbox_square-blue"
              increaseArea="20%"
              label="Checkbox"
            />

            <Checkbox
              id="checkbox1"
              checkboxClass="icheckbox_square-blue"
              increaseArea="20%"
            />
            <label for="checkbox1">First name</label>

            <Radio
              name="aa"
              radioClass="iradio_square-blue"
              increaseArea="20%"
              label="Radio"
            />


          </div>
          :
          null
        }
        {style.unuse()}

        </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Criteria;
```

However, now I get:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'raw'
```

How could I use `style-loader` properly?

Comment: If you're using webpack, you'll need `style-loader` and `css-loader`

Comment: I updated my code to use `style-loader`.

Comment: you'd need `webpack.config.js` to configure and use webpack loaders.

Comment: What code would I need to add in `webpack.config.js`?

Answer (score 1):

In your webpack config loader section add

```
module: {
   loaders: [
      {
        test      : /\.scss$/,
        include   : path.join(__dirname, 'sass'),
        loaders   : ["style", "css?sourceMap", "sass?sourceMap"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

By adding this code you have added three loaders namely (style,css and sass).

These three loaders perform following operations

- Turn your scss files into plain CSS with the sass loader
- Resolve all the imports and url(...)s in the CSS with the help of CSS loader
- Insert those styles into the page with the style loader

Then require your css file from the entry point of your app e.g app.js

```
require('app.scss');
```

**Edit:** If you are not using sass then you don't need sass loader, also you need to change `test:/\.css$/`

Comment: I added the loader and I put this in `index.jsx`(the main `jsx` component): 
`require("icheck/skins/all.css");` Now I get: `ERROR in ./~/icheck/skins/all.css
Module parse failed: node_modules/icheck/skins/all.css Line 3: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Comment: Have you added them as dependency inside `package.json` and installed these loader via `npm install` ?

Comment: Yes, I installed the packages and added the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Add `webpack` to your `devDependencies` in `package.json` using `npm i css-loader style-loader`. After that add the `css-loader` and `style-loader` to your list of loaders in `webpack.config.js`. Sample

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.css?$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css']
    }]
  }
}
```

Once you have added the loaders to config, you can import your css files in you components

Comment: I added that loader to the code. Now I get:  `Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/icheck/skins/polaris/polaris.css 6:1430-1457`

Comment: I have updated the loader names. Can you try with the updated one?

Comment: It's the same message but the error now appears in `ERROR in ./~/icheck/skins/flat/purple@2x.png`

Comment: I didn't get it. How is the error same if you its for `.png` file and not `.css`? Are you loading `.png` images dynamically as well?

Comment: Sorry, the messages is almost the same, but now for `.png` instead of `.css` so I seem to have made progress. If I change the code to `test: /\.(png|css)?$/,` the error becomes `ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/icheck/skins/polaris/polaris.png
Module build failed: CssSyntaxError: /css-loader!= node_modules/icheck/skins/polaris/polaris.png:45:161: Unclosed
quote` . In conclusion, it looks like it doesn't understand `.png` files. They are not mine, they belong to `icheck`.

Comment: ok. so maybe you can use image loaders for webpack. I am not sure about `icheck` but if you are using images you can use `url-loader?mimetype=image/png` loader to load your images as explained https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#query-parameters